# Fibonacci calculator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fibonacci-sequence

I'm just starting to look into Haskell. I've written a naive Fibonacci implementation, and I've also written a more advanced one that uses tail-call recursion for efficiency.

```
module Fibonacci where

import System.Environment

fibonacci :: Integer -> Integer
fibonacci 0 = 0
fibonacci 1 = 1
fibonacci n
    | n < 0 = error "Cannot find a negative fibonacci number"
    | otherwise = fibonacci (n - 1) + fibonacci (n - 2)

fibonacci' :: Integer -> Integer
fibonacci' n
    | n < 0 = error "Cannot find a negative fibonacci number"
    | otherwise = fibHelper n 0 1
    where
        fibHelper :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
        fibHelper n a b
            | n == 0 = a
            | otherwise = fibHelper (n - 1) b (a + b)

firstNumberFrom :: [String] -> Integer
firstNumberFrom [] = 10
firstNumberFrom args = read $ args !! 0

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let num = firstNumberFrom args in
        putStrLn $ show (fibonacci' num)
```

I'd appreciate any reviews on correctness and idiomatic usage.

Comment: What is your purpose behind implementing a naive fibonacci function? Are you familiar with its the limitations? Are you familiar with more efficient fibonacci algorithms?

Comment: The Haskell wiki has an article with many different Fibonacci implementations: https://wiki.haskell.org/The_Fibonacci_sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The many approaches in `main` and `firstNumberFrom` can be unified:

```
main = print . fibonacci' . maybe 10 read . listToMaybe =<< getArgs
```

The explicit recursion in `fibbonacci'` is captured by `iterate`:

```
fibbonacci' n = fst $ iterate (\(a,b) -> (b, a+b)) (0,1) !! n
```